# how to put many doughnut in same div using chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts

Here is the code... I thought by doubling the  code I would get two charts one next to each other... but it doesn't work... is it my html ? or am I missing something in the js ?

```
   <canvas id="canvas" height="200" width="200">


    <script>

    var doughnutData = [

            {
                value : 54.9865,
                color : "#46BFBD"
            },
            {
                value : 45.0135,
                color : "#FFFFFF"
            }

        ];


var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);

</script>


<canvas id="canvas" height="200" width="400">

    <script>

    var doughnutData = [

            {
                value : 54.9865,
                color : "#46BFBD"
            },
            {
                value : 45.0135,
                color : "#FFFFFF"
            }

        ];


var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);

</script>
</canvas>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

okay firstly calling it again will just call it over the first instance so that is why you are only getting one doughnut.

to fix this first you need to add another canvas element to your div so it should be something like:

```
<div>
    <canvas id="can1" width="300"></canvas>
    <canvas id="can2" width="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

then you need two data sets to work with like so:

```
<script>
    var dd1 = [
        {
            value : 54.9865,
            color : "#46BFBD"
        },
        {
            value : 45.0135,
            color : "#FFFFFF"
        }
    ];
    var dd2 = [
        {
            value : 54.9865,
            color : "#46BFBD"
        },
        {
            value : 45.0135,
            color : "#FFFFFF"
        }
    ];
</script>
```

then you need to call 2 charts like so:

```
<script>
    var dd1 = [
        {
            value : 54.9865,
            color : "#46BFBD"
        },
        {
            value : 45.0135,
            color : "#FFFFFF"
        }
    ];
    var dd2 = [
        {
            value : 54.9865,
            color : "#46BFBD"
        },
        {
            value : 45.0135,
            color : "#FFFFFF"
        }
    ];

    var dougnut1 = new Chart(document.getElementById("can1").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(dd1);
    var dougnut2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("can2").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(dd2);
</script>
```

hope this helps